# R Data Manipulation, convert flat table to structure table

Tags: r, data.table, transformation, spread

my goal is to convert a data.frame of the form:

```
ID 1    ID 2    Value
5        k        7
5        k        2
5        l        4
6        b        2
```

into a table of the form:

```
ID 1    k    l    b
5       7    4      
6                 2
```

I would then like to manipulate the data and go back to the first format again.

I tried it by using the function spread() in the library(tidyr) but do only get the following format (which is not what I want) :

```
ID 1    k   l   b
5       7       
5       7       
5           4   
6               2
```

thanks for your help

Comment: There's an issue with the data: combination of ID1 = 5/ID2 = k is not unique. There are two values associated with it. Where did the value "2" go? Or you are interested in max value? Also, after aggregation, there is no way to go back to the original format as you have lost some information in the process.

Comment: Concise one liner with data.table package: `library(data.table); dcast(setDT(df)[, Value[1], .(ID1, ID2)], ID1 ~ ID2)`

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear how you want to handle duplicates but here is an attempt,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df[!duplicated(df[c('ID1', 'ID2')]),] %>% 
                                    group_by(ID1) %>% 
                                    spread(ID2, Value, fill = '')

df1
#Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
#Groups: ID1 [2]

#    ID1     b     k     l
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     5           7     4
#2     6     2
```

To go back to the original we need to `gather`, i.e.

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
         gather(ID2, Value, b:l) %>% 
         filter(Value != '') 

df2
#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#Groups: ID1 [2]

#    ID1   ID2 Value
#  <int> <chr> <chr>
#1     6     b     2
#2     5     k     7
#3     5     l     4
```

However, we are missing the duplicates so we `rbind` them to the `gather`ed data frame, i.e.

```
rbind(as.data.frame(df2), df[duplicated(df[c('ID1', 'ID2')]),])
#    ID1 ID2 Value
#1    6   b     2
#2    5   k     7
#3    5   l     4
#21   5   k     2
```

After your clarification, if you don't have duplicates then,

```
df1 <- df %>% group_by(ID1) %>% spread(ID2, Value, fill = '')
```

and to go back to the original

```
df2 <- df1 %>% gather(ID2, Value, b:l) %>% filter(Value != '')
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution to your problem would be following:

```
x <- data.frame(ID1 = c(5,5,5,6),
                ID2 = c("k","k","l","b"),
                Value = c(7,2,4,2))

x <- dcast(x, ID1 ~ ID2, value.var = "Value", fun.aggregate = max, fill = 0)

> x
  ID1 b k l
1   5 0 7 4
2   6 2 0 0
```

That's given that I handled the non-unique values of ID1/ID2 combinations with `max` function. Move in the opposite direction would be with `melt` function... but there is no way we can recover values lost in aggregation:

```
melt(x, id.vars = "ID1", variable.name = "ID2")
```

Comment: Sorry there was indeed an error in my data provided. please ignore the second line. the initial data.frame should be

Comment: ID 1    ID 2    Value
    5        k        7
    5        l        4
    6        b        2

Comment: sorry, no clue how to edit. Just without the second row in the first data frame and without the second row in the last data frame provided in the initial post. @A. Val. I assume your approach would still be valide just without the max function?

Comment: Yes, aggregation function is required only when there is collision of non-unique ID values.

Comment: @Walde to edit click on [edit below your post or on this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39992353/edit)